# Load another page when iframe loads

Tags: iframe

Hey all thx for your time!!.

I want to add a login page at my website. So, i am using iframe and centered it to show the username,password and connect button. But, i want my page to load the iframe page when user click the connect button inside the iframe.

First, i want them to add the username and password info. And click load, then the page reloads but keeps their info (i hope).

Here is the code

```
<iframe id="iframe" scrolling="no" 
    src="http://sms.altasoft.gr/panel/index.asp?lang=el&disp_function=user_login&id=5E8A0F4B-063B-4A7A-81FE-99579AF44BAA">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the page loaded into the iframe uses some cookies to keep the log in information, this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var iFrame = document.getElementById("iframe");
        iFrame.onload = function(){
            window.location = iFrame.src;
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're using an iframe and want to have the main page reload when the form inside the iframe has been submitted. Is that correct? If so, add ' target="_top"' to the form inside the iframe, and it should reload the whole thing.